# How can I dynamically set a property on an object in right way?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm using **Typescript**. I would like to know how I can dynamically set a property on an object, so that Typescript recognizes the assignment.

For example,

```
class Foo {
    constructor(obj: object) {
        for (const key in obj) {
            this[key] = obj[key]
        }
    }
}

const bar = new Foo({
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
});

bar.x; // Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Foo'
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
class State {
    private state: string;

    constructor (states: string[]) {
        states.forEach((x) => {
            this[x] = () => this.state = x;
        });
    }
}

const x = new State(['open', 'closed']);

x.open(); // Property 'open' does not exist on type 'State'.
```

Comment: is `a` a typo? i don't see any `a` in your code

Comment: @sag1v I just fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: I remove my answer after the edit then

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Current example doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: I added more information. What about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I don't think TypeScript has a good way for a static class to extend a generic type.  What I mean, the following *invalid* TypeScript is sort of what you're asking for:

```
// doesn't work
class Foo<T> extends T {
  constructor(obj: T) {
    for (const key in obj) {
      this[key] = obj[key];
    }
  }
}
```

So you want something *like* a [mixin class](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13743), where you extend `Foo` to be a constructor of both `Foo` and `T`... but not exactly.  Here is the best I can do:

Create a class with a different name, `_Foo`, which adds all the `Foo`-specific methods and properties.  Note that you have to assert `this` to be of type `T` in order to assign `T`'s properties to it:

```
class _Foo<T> {
  constructor(obj: T) {
    for (const key in obj) {
      // assert this to be compatible with T
      (this as any as T)[key] = obj[key];
    }
  }
  // Foo-specific properties and methods go here
}
```

Then you can define the type `Foo<T>` to be both `_Foo<T>` and `T`, and assert that `Foo` is also an object which acts as a constructor for `Foo<T>`:

```
type Foo<T> = T & _Foo<T>;
const Foo = _Foo as { new <T>(obj: T): Foo<T> };
```

And now use it:

```
const bar = new Foo({
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
});

bar.x; // okay
```

Does that work for you?  It might be worth mentioning that the difficulty involved here might be an indication that what you're trying to do may be better achieved in TypeScript by another design.  For instance, maybe `Foo<T>` should just *have* a `T`, instead of *be* one.  Then you can do this in a more straightforward manner.  But that's up to you.

Hope it helps; good luck!